# Flutter: Index out of range

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a dynamic slider. I tried different ways to implement this slide that I wanted to create. When I try to use that code I'm getting an error:
**RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 75: 75**. I don't why. But when I change `category[count]` to `category[i]` error is gone but same value repeats.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Category> category = widget.category;
    int slideLenght = ((category.length / 14).floor()) + 1;
    List<Widget> slides = [];
    List categoryForSlide = [];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < slideLenght; i++) {
      List<Category> subCat = List();

      for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        if (i == 14) break;
        subCat.add(category[count]);
        print(count);
        count++;
      }
      categoryForSlide.add(subCat);
    }
    print(categoryForSlide.length);
    return Container(),
    );
```

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve].  Yo are referencing variables in the example that are not defined.

Comment: Have you tried to set different variable names for loops? Both loops are using `i`, which is not recommended.

Comment: Ya. I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply have to reset `count` to `0` or define it in the outer loop :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Category> category = widget.category;
    int slideLenght = ((category.length / 14).floor()) + 1;
    List<Widget> slides = [];
    List categoryForSlide = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slideLenght; i++) {
      var count = 0;
      List<Category> subCat = List();

      for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        if (i == 14) break;
        subCat.add(category[count]);
        print(count);
        count++;
      }
      categoryForSlide.add(subCat);
    }
    print(categoryForSlide.length);
    return Container();
};
```

Also as pointed out by Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα in the comments, it is not a good practice to use the same `i` variable name for both your nested loops.

So a simplified version would be :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Category> category = widget.category;
    int slideLenght = ((category.length / 14).floor()) + 1;
    List<Widget> slides = [];
    List categoryForSlide = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slideLenght; i++) {
      List<Category> subCat = List();

      for (var j = 0; j < category.length; j++) {
        if (j == 14) break;
        subCat.add(category[j]);
        print(j);
      }
      categoryForSlide.add(subCat);
    }
    print(categoryForSlide.length);
    return Container();
};
```

**EDIT** : OK as I understand you want to display 14 categories per slide, you should have mentionned this in your question.

The solution you posted works but is not optimal IMO, you could do it simpler using a modulo operator.

See this example, it adds 3 categories per slide :

```dart
void main() {
  final List<String> categories = List<String>.generate(10, (counter) => "Category $counter");
  final int nbCategoriesPerPage = 3;
  List<List<String>> slides = [[]];

  int slideIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0 && i % nbCategoriesPerPage == 0) {
      slides.add(List());
      slideIndex++;
    }
    slides[slideIndex].add(categories[i]);
  }

  print(slides);
}
```

Output:

> [[Category 0, Category 1, Category 2], [Category 3, Category 4,
> Category 5], [Category 6, Category 7, Category 8], [Category 9]]

Hope it helps.

Comment: this would work. but all the values will be repeated.

Comment: Yes of course, you always loop on the same `category` variable. It could have been what you wanted, it all depends on your business case. The answer aims to solve your technical problem, but it seems you also have a design problem here, what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final List<Category> category = widget.category;
int slideLenght = ((category.length / 14).floor()) + 1;
List<Widget> slides = [];
List categoryForSlide = [];
var count = 0;
var f = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < slideLenght; i++) {
  List<Category> subCat = List();
  for (var z = 0; z < category.length; z++) {
    if (count < category.length) {
      count++;
    }
    subCat.add(category[count - 1]);
    if (count == category.length) break;
    if (z == 14) break;
  }

  categoryForSlide.add(subCat);
}
    print(categoryForSlide.length);
    return Container();
}
```

Comment: This may work but I think you could do it simpler using a modulo, I have edited my answer to add an example. Alsonote that your `f`` variable is useless and you could group the `if` statements.